# React Data Grid (adazzle) : TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React and I am using adazzle's React Data Grid to create an editable grid in my React application. My code below compiles successfully but when I try to run it on http://localhost:3000, it gives me the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". Please help as I cannot see where I use the length property in my code.

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ReactDataGrid from "react-data-grid";
import "./styles.css";

const columns = [
  { key: "id", name: "ID", editable: true },
  { key: "title", name: "Title", editable: true },
  { key: "complete", name: "Complete", editable: true }
];

const rows = [
  { id: 0, title: "Task 1", complete: 20 },
  { id: 1, title: "Task 2", complete: 40 },
  { id: 2, title: "Task 3", complete: 60 }
];

class Example extends React.Component {
  state = { rows };

  onGridRowsUpdated = ({ fromRow, toRow, updated }) => {
    this.setState(state => {
      const rows = state.rows.slice();
      for (let i = fromRow; i <= toRow; i++) {
        rows[i] = { ...rows[i], ...updated };
      }
      return { rows };
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <ReactDataGrid
        //rows={rows]  //uncomment this line and the grid appears successfully but cannot be edited(?)
        columns={columns}
        rowGetter={i => this.state.rows[i]}
        rowsCount={3}
        onGridRowsUpdated={this.onGridRowsUpdated}
        enableCellSelect={true}
      />
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, rootElement);
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the error message in detail:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
(anonymous function)
C:/kilostep_material/src/hooks/useViewportRows.ts:31
  28 |   expandedGroupIds
  29 | }: ViewportRowsArgs<R>) {
  30 |   const [groupedRows, rowsCount] = useMemo(() => {
> 31 |     if (groupBy.length === 0 || !rowGrouper) return [undefined, rawRows.length];
  32 | 
  33 |     const groupRows = (rows: readonly R[], [groupByKey, ...remainingGroupByKeys]: readonly string[], startRowIndex: number): [GroupByDictionary<R>, number] => {
  34 |       let groupRowsCount = 0;
View compiled
▼ 3 stack frames were expanded.
mountMemo
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15846
useMemo
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16219
useMemo
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1532
▲ 3 stack frames were expanded.
useViewportRows
C:/kilostep_material/src/hooks/useViewportRows.ts:30
  27 |   rowGrouper,
  28 |   expandedGroupIds
  29 | }: ViewportRowsArgs<R>) {
> 30 |   const [groupedRows, rowsCount] = useMemo(() => {
  31 |     if (groupBy.length === 0 || !rowGrouper) return [undefined, rawRows.length];
  32 | 
  33 |     const groupRows = (rows: readonly R[], [groupByKey, ...remainingGroupByKeys]: readonly string[], startRowIndex: number): [GroupByDictionary<R>, number] => {
View compiled
DataGrid
C:/kilostep_material/src/DataGrid.tsx:268
  265 |   rawGroupBy: rowGrouper ? rawGroupBy : undefined
  266 | });
  267 | 
> 268 | const { rowOverscanStartIdx, rowOverscanEndIdx, rows, rowsCount, isGroupRow } = useViewportRows({
      | ^  269 |   rawRows,
  270 |   groupBy,
  271 |   rowGrouper,
View compiled
▼ 17 stack frames were expanded.
renderWithHooks
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14985
updateForwardRef
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17044
beginWork
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19098
HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4056
beginWork$1
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23964
performUnitOfWork
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22776
workLoopSync
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22707
renderRootSync
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22670
performSyncWorkOnRoot
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22293
scheduleUpdateOnFiber
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21881
updateContainer
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25482
(anonymous function)
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26021
unbatchedUpdates
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22431
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26020
render
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:26103
▲ 17 stack frames were expanded.
Module.<anonymous>
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/src/index.js:44
  41 | }
  42 | 
  43 | const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
> 44 | ReactDOM.render(<Example />, rootElement);
  45 | 
View compiled
Module../src/index.js
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:203:30
__webpack_require__
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/webpack/bootstrap:851
  848 | 
  849 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  850 | try {
> 851 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  852 | } finally {
  853 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  854 | }
View compiled
fn
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
1
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:309:18
__webpack_require__
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/webpack/bootstrap:851
  848 | 
  849 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  850 | try {
> 851 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  852 | } finally {
  853 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  854 | }
View compiled
checkDeferredModules
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/webpack/bootstrap:45
  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | 
View compiled
Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push]
C:/kilostep_material/kilostep/webpack/bootstrap:32
  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;
View compiled
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:69
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.  Click the 'X' or hit ESC to dismiss this message.
```

Comment: Your code is exactly what's in the `react-data-grid` example demo sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/5vy2q8owj4?from-embed. I don't see anywhere in the code anything accessing a `length` property. Can you provide the exact and complete error message in your question? We should be able to see what the undefined reference is.

Comment: I have updated my post with the detailed error message.

Comment: I browsed through the adazzle github issues forum and found this : 

https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/issues/2030

I changed my code to below and the grid displays but I could not edit :

render() {
    return (
      <ReactDataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
      />
    );
  }

Comment: Possible versioning issue. The linked codesandbox demo of theirs is running `react-data-grid` v5.0.1. That github issue trackers implies that newer versions may have some issues or be a little buggy.

Comment: Thank you very, very much Drew! I was suspecting the same thing! Well... reverting to 5.0.1....(couldn't find any editable React data grids on the Net except this one)

Comment: I changed package.json to use React-Data-Grid 5.0.1 but I keep getting the "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined error although the vendor sandbox example worked. When I add the line : rows={rows} in the return statement, the grid displays fine but it can't be edited.

Comment: Are you trying to get a clone of `react-data-grid` example demo working locally or do you have an actual code example that isn't working? Can you create a *running* codesandbox for your code that we can examine and live debug in?

Comment: I am trying to get  a clone of the react-data-grid example sandbox demo working locally. I am using Visual Code Express on my laptop on localhost:3000. I have got other React apps working normally including axios and Material-UI Data Grid. As I mentioned earlier, there is actually a GitHub Issue posted on the same error I got at :  github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/issues/2030 so somebody else is facing the same issue.  (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) I put the additional line: rows={rows} in the return statement (as advised by the accepted comment from the GitHub issue and presto, the grid does finally display normally without error, but then I find I am unable to edit the grid. When I remove the line : rows={rows} as in my code posted originally (and the original sandbox code), I get the : Cannot read property 'length' error. Initially I used React-Data-Grid 7.0.1 Canary but I changed it to version 5.0.1 as you advised (and like in the sandbox example) and yet the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the React Data Grid to run and be editable as in the example sandbox code by uninstalling the 7.0.1 version and installing the 5.0.1 version which was the one in use by the sandbox (although there are other sandboxes with earlier versions e.g. 3.0.2 which also works).

I typed the following commands:

npm uninstall react-data-grid

npm install react-data-grid@5.0.1

Or with yarn:

yarn remove react-data-grid

yarn add react-data-grid@5.0.1